# Error en directivas de Google API

Tags: c#, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-api

Tengo una función lo cual estoy tratando de abrir un archivo de excel en formato de `bytes` usando la API de Google Sheets `Google Sheets API`, usando la versión `1.57.0.2826`.

Pero me da un error en una función en la parte de la función `Media`, que me dice que no existe

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public ActionResult Abrir(int id)
        {
            // Obtener el archivo en formato byte[] desde la base de datos
            byte[] archivoBytes = ObtenerArchivo(id);

            // Cargar las credenciales de autenticación desde un archivo JSON en tu proyecto
            string rutaCreadencial = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Excels/client_secret_575240326073-p10cntjcu8c5a31o8ps05mq02oksqv7l.apps.googleusercontent.com.json");
            GoogleCredential credenciales = GoogleCredential.FromFile(rutaCreadencial).CreateScoped(SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets);

            // Crear un objeto SheetsService utilizando las credenciales de autenticación
            var servicio = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credenciales,
                ApplicationName = "MesaGL7"
            });

            // Cargar el archivo de Excel desde los bytes
            var stream = new MemoryStream(archivoBytes);

            // Cargar el archivo de Excel en un nuevo Google Spreadsheet
            var request = servicio.Spreadsheets.Create(new Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data.Spreadsheet());
            request.Media = new Google.Apis.Upload.ResumableUpload.MediaUpload(stream, "application/vnd.ms-excel");

        }
```

Comment: Luisito, ¿qué dice la documentación? ¿Hubo algún cambio de versiones anteriores a la versión actual con ese método?

Comment: Hola Fredy, he intentado con la ultima versión pero igual así me dice lo mismo.

Comment: Referencia: https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Apis/latest/Google.Apis.Upload.ResumableUpload